# Get value from jquery object

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get value of description from jQuery object. my object something like this.
[image]

I am using `JSON.parse` but with this, I am getting undefined.

Comment: Please provide details as text not only screen shot

Comment: objectname.description ?

Comment: I am getting this in ajax response and trying to fetch description.

Comment: I already try something like this." objectname.description". But this is also not working. and this objectname[description] also

Comment: Can you dump the interesting part of your js here  ?

Comment: @SoniaSarangal here's a good SO post on js data structures http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1385672

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we get the object from data variable. You get it like

```
console.log(data[0].description);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
objectName[0].description
```